# Array de objetos no TypeScript quando altera-se um valor os demais são alterados

Tags: typescript

Eu tenho essa classe em TypeScript

```
export class PageModel {

  constructor () {
  }

  Name: string;
  Content: string;
  Url: string;

}
```

E criei um array dessa classe

```
let test: PageModel[];
test = new Array(21);
test.fill(new PageModel());
test.fill(new PageModel());
```

Setei esse array com duas instancias:

```
test[0].Content = 'Firt instatance';
test[1].Content = 'Second instatance' ;
console.log (test[0].Content + test[1].Content);
```

Porém no console é mostrado 'Second instance Second instance'

O segundo valor sobescreve o primeiro valor.

Existe alguma maneira para solucionar esse problema?

Comment: traduzido o post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja a documentação do [`Array.prototye.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

> O método `fill()` **preenche todos os valores do array** a partir do índice inicial a um índice final com um valor estático.

Ou seja, todas as posições do seu *array* serão exatamente a mesma instância e ao modificá-la em um dos índices, a mudança será refletida em todos os outros. Como você já iniciou o *array* com 21 posições, você não precisa utilizar o `fill()`, basta atribuir a instância no índice desejado:

```
test[0] = new PageModel();
test[1] = new PageModel();
```

Ou, se não desejar inicializar um a um, pode utilizar o `fill` para inicializá-los todos com `undefined` e mapeá-los para uma nova instância da classe que deseja:

```
test = new Array(21).fill().map(it => new PageModel());
```

Exemplo:

```js
class PageModel {}

const test = new Array(5).fill().map(it => new PageModel())

test[0].name = 'foo'
test[1].name = 'bar'

console.log(test);
```

Comment: funcionou obrigado pela resposta. Ajudou muito